# How can I remove a list entry in a dictionary of lists?

Tags: list, dictionary, python-3.4

I can't seem to iterate through a list in a dictionary.

```
data={}
data['people']=[]
data['people'].append({'Name':'Michael'})
data['people'].append({'Name':'Paul'})

for idx, val in data['people']:
    if val == {'Name':'Michael'}:del data['people'][idx]
```

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
data={}
data['people']=[]
data['people'].append({'Name':'Michael'})
data['people'].append({'Name':'Paul'})

for i in data['people']:
    if i == {'Name':'Michael'}:
        data['people'].remove(i)
```

Comment: @Jat T. Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I was confused and was trying to remove it as if was a dictionary using `clear()` or `del`.